# Awk to replace a column with another column if it meets criteria

Tags: unix, awk

In psudocode, I'm trying to replace column 4 with column 1, if column 4 equals NULL. Otherwise keep column 4 the same. I'm currently trying this, which isn't changing the line and I'm not sure why:
Example data:

```
grep NULL matrix.txt
```

AAGGGCCCGGGGGG  0   0   3   NULL

```
grep NULL matrix.txt | awk -F/t '{ $34 = ($34 == "NULL" ? $1 : $34) } 1'
```

Should give me:

AAGGGCCCGGGGGG  0   0   3   AAGGGCCCGGGGGG

Thanks!

Comment: No need to use `grep`, since `awk` can do the search as well

Answer (score 3):

modify your **awk**

replace `$34` with `$5` as you need to check `5th` field not `34th`

Also `/t` is incorrect. It should be `\t` for tab. BTW it will also work without `-F "\t"`

```
echo "AAGGGCCCGGGGGG 0 0 3 NULL"  | awk ' $5=="NULL"{$5=$1} 1'
```

Comment: It's actually the 5th, isn't it. I don't know why OP wrote 4th, when in the example it looks like the 5th.

Comment: @janos: Oops .. Thanks for correcting janos. Even I didn't pay that attention to it.

Comment: @janos The OP said *column 4*, not *the 4th column*. I guess the OP thinks that column numbers start with `0` in awk.

Comment: Thank you. I have many more columns and had tried to shorten it for clarity, but missed changing some variables. This worked great.